# How can I specify many child types in inner_hits elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have many parent-child relationships in my ES all of them pointing to the same parent type.

I am interrogating the ES with inner-hits.

Can I specify more than one child type?

`POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "my_child"...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify more than one child type using [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html):

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
     "bool" : {
        "should" : [
          { "has_child" : { "type": "my_child"... } },
          { "has_child" : { "type": "my_child2"... } }
        ]
     }
  }
}
```